# Powershell Issues with .contains function for strings

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-1.0

OK, i am trying to get this script to work and not continuously hit the same computers over and over and am having trouble getting it working. I don't think this is the best way to do it and if you have any suggestions please and thank you. Anyways there seems to be an issue with line 6 "IF (!$Succssful.Contains($Computer)) {" it doesn't shoot an error at me but instead ends the script per-maturealy. I have tried removing the "!" but no luck as I expected.

```
$Computers = "TrinityTechCorp"
$HotFixes = Get-Content HotFixes.csv

While ($Successful -AND $Successful.count -ne $Computers.count) {
    ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
        IF (!$Succssful.Contains($Computer)) {
            If (Test-Connection $Computer) {
                $Comparison = get-hotfix -ComputerName $Computer | Select -expand HotFixID
                ForEach ($HotFix in $HotFixes) {
                IF ($Comparison -NotLike "*$HotFix*") {
                    Write-Host "$Computer missing $HotFix"
                }
                $Successful += $Computer
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a lot of computers to run this on, I would suggest including Invoke-Command to run it on all computers in parallell. remember to put hotfix.csv on a public networkshare. Invoke-Command -Computername test1, test2 -ScriptBlock { your script } would return all the write-host messages in a single output that you could save in a file or whatever.

Comment: btw. What is while ($successful) isn't  .. isn't successful a string[]?. Also, since successful is a list of machines, you would want to move `$successful += $computer` outside of the hotfix loop(on step out), because now the computername is added on each hotfix-test

Comment: Where is `$successful` defined? I think we're missing some of your script.

Comment: Your typo in line 6 -- "Succssful" should be "Successful" -- may be part of the problem.

Comment: Graimer - 
Thank you for the idea, but I need to get the current script working before I think about adding that. Also the !$Successful checks to see if $Successful is defined. This makes it so I do not have to declare it before i can check it in the if statement. 

KeithHill - 
$Successful is defined later in the script, i add the computer name of each successful computer to it.

msorens - 
Thank you for that, fixed it and still not having any luck getting the script to work. >.> back to the drawing board.

Comment: ".Contains()" compares the list objects, so in a way it is case sensitive. you could change line 6 to:
IF (-not($Successful -contains $Computer)) {

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
While ($Successful -AND $Successful.count -ne $Computers.count) {
```

can never evaluate to $true.  The `.count`-property of a non-existing variable ($Successful) is $null, and the same goes for a string (because you specify only 1 computer, it's not an array).

To force Powershell to return the "true" number of items, use `@($Successful).count` and  `@($Computers).count` instead.  This will give you 1, even if $Computers wasn't defined as an array.  So, with variables substituted, your line is interpreted as

```
While ($null -AND $null.count -ne $null) {
```

In Powershell 3, as you can read [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/scriptfanatic/archive/2012/03/19/Counting-objects-in-PowerShell-3.0.aspx), this is no longer the case.